# Popup MSG and Disable Submit Button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to Popup a MSG and Disable Submit Button if id="Country" dose not equal option value="US" I think I'm close but cant seem to figure it out:

CODE:

```
<html>
<body>

<script>

$(document).on('change','#Country',function () {

    if ((value1 != "US")) {
         alert( my error message);
         SubmitButton = "disabled";
    }

});
</script>


<select id="Country">
     <option value="US">United States</option>
     <option value="CAN">Canada</option>
     <option value="JAP">Jspan</option>
</select>

<br /><br />

<input id="SubmitButton" type="button" value="Submit">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had several errors, here is the fixed code:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhjv3947/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Country").on('change', function () {
        if ($(this).val() != "US") {
            alert("my error message");
            $("#SubmitButton").prop("disabled",true);
        }
    });
});
```

- One error was no quotes around "my error message"
- Another was that you didn't have your DOM loaded before this script ran. I wrapped your code in `$(document).ready( function() { ... });`, doing this will mean you don't need to use delegation from the document.
- Another was that you were never setting "value1", I changed it to just directly get the value - `$(this).val()`
- Another was you need to actually get the SubmitButton to disable it. Get it with `$("#SubmitButton")` and disable with `.prop("disabled",true)`

Also, if you want to re-enable the submit button if the user selects US, you can do this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhjv3947/1/)

```
        ...
        $("#SubmitButton").prop("disabled",true);
    } else {
        $("#SubmitButton").prop("disabled",false);
    }
...
```

Comment: there is a diff b/w attr and prop please go through

Comment: @Sunand, true enough, `.prop()` should be used for `disabled`

Comment: bad that i can not reply smiley alone :)

Comment: smery Works but the button stays disabled after a error MSG

Comment: @Bill, I updated my answer, let me know if that is what you meant.

Comment: Disabled only if != US enabled if == US

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `attr()`

```
$("#SubmitButton").attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: `.prop(.., ..)` should be used for `disabled` instead of `.attr(.., ..)`.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive its not

```
SubmitButton = "disabled";
```

It should be

```
$("#SubmitButton").prop("disabled",true);
```